# How to set CSS auto complete box (ul) same size with search box (input) on tailwind?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

[image]

How to resolve tailwind css styling issues?

Can anyone help me why searchbox `input` and autocomplete items `ul` come with different size?  Here is my code, both class are w-full.

```js
      <div className="sticky top-20 z-40 w-full px-1 sm:p-5 md:p-10">
        <div className="gap-1">
          <form onSubmit={handleSearchClick} className="">
            {/* <SearchDropdown /> */}
            <input
              enterKeyHint="search"
              type="search"
              className={`w-full bg-white px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 ${
                autoResults.length > 0
                  ? "rounded-tl-3xl rounded-tr-3xl"
                  : "rounded-full"
              } z-10 border focus:border-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-40`}
              placeholder=" Search for products"
              onChange={handleInput}
              onClick={() => {
                setAutoResults(searchInput.length > 0 ? trackResults : []);
              }}
              value={searchInput}
            />
            {autoResults.length > 0 && (
              <ul className="absolute w-full rounded-bl-3xl rounded-br-3xl border-r border-l border-b bg-white focus:border-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-40">
                {autoResults.map((result: any) => {
                  return (
                    <li
                      className=" cursor-pointer border-gray-300 p-2 px-4 text-gray-700 hover:bg-blue-400"
                      key={result._id}
                      // onClick={() => setSearchInput(result._id)}
                      onClick={() => handleSelect(result._id)}
                      // value={result._id}
                    >
                      {result._id}
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            )}
          </form>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep `ul` from `overflowing`, try add a `relative` class to the `form` container so that `ul` is placed relative to it.

On a side note, perhaps consider also to add a `overflow-hidden` to `ul` so that its background color is contained in the rounded border.

Here is a minimized example with no functionality, just styles: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hujtwd?file=src/App.jsx)

Example:

```
<div className="sticky top-20 z-40 w-full px-1 sm:p-5 md:p-10">
  <div className="gap-1">
    {/*  Add "relative" class here */}
    <form onSubmit={handleSearchClick} className="relative">
      {/* <SearchDropdown /> */}
      <input
        enterKeyHint="search"
        type="search"
        className={`w-full bg-white px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 ${
          autoResults.length > 0
            ? "rounded-tl-3xl rounded-tr-3xl"
            : "rounded-full"
        } z-10 border focus:border-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-40`}
        placeholder=" Search for products"
        onChange={handleInput}
        onClick={() => {
          setAutoResults(searchInput.length > 0 ? trackResults : []);
        }}
        value={searchInput}
      />
      {autoResults.length > 0 && (
        <ul className="overflow-hidden absolute w-full rounded-bl-3xl rounded-br-3xl border-r border-l border-b bg-white focus:border-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-40">
          {/*  Consider to add "overflow-hidden" class here */}
          {autoResults.map((result: any) => {
            return (
              <li
                className=" cursor-pointer border-gray-300 p-2 px-4 text-gray-700 hover:bg-blue-400"
                key={result._id}
                // onClick={() => setSearchInput(result._id)}
                onClick={() => handleSelect(result._id)}
                // value={result._id}
              >
                {result._id}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.